# Get permutations of array with element fixed using next_permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I am aware that `next_permutations()` in the STL library gives you ALL the possible permutations. However, how can I get specific permutations with a fixed position.

An Example:
Suppose I have the bit format XXXXX(where X is 1 or 0). Can I do something where I keep the second index 1, say (now being X1XXX), and want to find all other permutations for that specific case? Basically, I want the final result as the permutations of ALL other positions when the second index is 1.

Something like (2nd element is always fixed as 1):

```
01000
01001
...
11000
..
```

Comment: what prevents you from just inserting a 1 into each permutation?

Comment: You don't need permutations to do that. Let say length of your string has to be `n` > 2, then generate  all possible bit strings of length n-2. Now in front of all these you can either add '01' or a '11'. Thus giving you all possibilities.